# FlipView SelectedItem is not showing when Changing View State?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using FlipView to show items (adding flip view item from code) and using VirtualizingStackpanel. when I change the View (snapView and fullmode)  will clear flipview items using FlipView.Item.Clear() and do some size calculation and again add items in the flipview. The issue is i am not able to see the item after this and if i tap to the other item and coming back i am able to see the item. Any idea what is causing the issue?

```
                <FlipView x:Name="fp" Margin="120,0,100,0"  Visibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="onSelectionChanged">
                <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel  x:Name="FlipView2ItemsPanel" Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                       </VirtualizingStackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
        </FlipView>
```

Comment: I've seen a similar issue with my custom ContentControl subclass that did not get its content updated when switching it on the view change from/to snapped view. I ended up having to use two separate set of controls for full/filled/portrait and snapped views and just switch visibilities.

Comment: ya i think that will be one of the easiest solution

Comment: Fortunately Win 8 PCs will likely not be impacted by such inefficiencies as much as phones. It's also likely a bug that will be fixed soon.